# I have added Interceptor in angular which will add a custom header to request, after adding it iam getting CORS error when calling API endpoint

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cookies, cors, interceptor

I have added Interceptor in angular which will add a custom header to request, after adding it iam getting CORS error when calling API endpoint

Tried adding

but my teamlead saying dont modify web.config, it's not the way to solve it.. you should check why cookies are not getting passed with the request and try to pass them instead of this.. but cookies are getting passed with the request without interceptor change..

Comment: This needs more information. Please improve your question so we can answer it.